# How to escape special characters in maven properties

Tags: maven, properties, escaping, maven-archetype, unicode-escapes

I am using an archetype to generate a project, and as part of this I need to dynamically generate a property within the pom file.

The problem is that the name of a property in maven does not allow the dollar sign ($), and this sign is needed to denote a property defined in the archetype generation step.

E.g. I need to achieve:

```
   <${property}.version>[0,)</${property}.version>
```

But maven does not allow this, and the pom becomes corrupt.

I have searched and attempted the following but none of them work:

- Using double dollar $$
- Using escape \$
- Using $
- Using the hexa notation for the dollar \u0024

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to achieve it?

Comment: tried to use `@` instead of `$`?

Comment: @khmarbaise Is this described in some doc I couldn't find at first sight?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, that still doesn't work. It stops the whole property being parsable.